# How to change ConsoleWrite to Label Text

Tags: c#

Well i have been putting my IP Get and console.write function, but there's one problem, that i don't know what Console.Write does and i just need that code would go to Label text, that means when the IP Is getting, it would go to Label.Text
BTW, i use Visual Studio c#.

```
private void metroLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         String strHostName = string.Empty;
         // Getting Ip address of local machine...
         // First get the host name of local machine.
         strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
         Console.WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);
         // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
         IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
         IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

         for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
            //metroLabel1.Text = " >> " + "", i, addr[i].ToString());
           // Console.WriteLine = metroLabel1.Text;

        }
         Console.ReadLine();



    }
```

Comment: If yo uwant to write a label, just assign it's text. If you want to keep this formating, Console.WriteLine() will call String.Fomat() to interpret that string with Placeholders. You can just as well call it manually.

Comment: So how could i make, that IP Address will be shown in Label?

Comment: If you do not even understand how to assign a value to a Field or Property, you really need to go 5 steps back and make a toutorial. If you have issues with that, you will have way more issues of this kind and Stackoverflow is not suiteable to be a Toutorial service.

Comment: I just started to create something 5 days ago, i don't know much things. ;/

Comment: `metroLabel1.Text += String.Format("IP Address {0}: {1} \r\n", i, addr[i]);`

Comment: Well, thanks for that, but maybe do you know, why when i run, it shows not IP But something like this : IP ADDRESS- Fe80::4ca.......

Comment: How could the code get and show the internet supplier IP?

Comment: I mean like how to get not Ipv6 but supplier IP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
metroLabel1.Text = inputString
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
string HostName = Dns.GetHostName();   
IPAddress[] ipaddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(HostName); 

//Label lblIPlist = new Label();  

foreach (IPAddress ip4 in ipaddress.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily==System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))  
{  
    //Console.WriteLine(ip4.ToString());  
    metroLabel1.Text += "IP Address: " + ip4.ToString() + "\n";
}  

//Console.WriteLine(metroLabel1.Text);


//foreach (IPAddress ip6 in ipaddress.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6))  
//{  
//  Console.WriteLine(ip6.ToString());  
//}
```

Refer [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm). It might be useful to you.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>
<sub>- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/getting-ip-address-and-host-name-using-dns-class/</sub>